# Matlab waiting for mouse click event during showing splash screen

Tags: matlab

Hi guys I have a question about following code:

```
im = imread('hans65.tif');

f = figure('visible','off');
imshow(im, 'Border', 'tight');
rectangle('Position', [950, 500, 20, 80], 'EdgeColor','k', 'FaceColor','k')
rectangle('Position', [920, 530, 80, 20], 'EdgeColor','k', 'FaceColor','k')

% rectangle('Position', [400, 100, 10, 10]);
% rectangle('Position', [600, 100, 10, 10]);

set(gcf,'PaperPositionMode','auto')
print(f, '-dpng', 'hans12.png');

% splash('hans12','png',10000);
splash('hans12','png',5000);
```

At the moment the code is loading a picture into matlab.
Changeing the picture and showing the safed picture in a splash screen.

What I want to do now is:

During I see the splash screen press the right or left mouse button to see another splash scrren (right pic1 and left pic2). 
I was searching in the internet but couldn't find any solution.

cheers guys!

I tried this:

```
function main

im = imread('hans65.tif');
f = figure('visible','off'); imshow(im, 'Border', 'tight');
rectangle('Position', [950, 500, 20, 80],...
 'EdgeColor', 'k',...
 'FaceColor','k')

rectangle('Position', [920, 530, 80, 20],...
 'EdgeColor', 'k',...
 'FaceColor','k')

rectangle('Position', [400, 100, 10, 10]);
rectangle('Position', [600, 100, 10, 10]);
set(gcf,'PaperPositionMode','auto')
print(f, '-dpng', 'hans12.png');

s = SplashScreen( 'Splashscreen', 'hans12.png');

set(s, 'buttondownfcn', @clicky);



function clicky(gcbo, eventdata, handles)
pause(4)
delete(s)
```

now I get this error message:

The name 'buttondownfcn' is not an accessible
property for an instance of class
'SplashScreen'.

I don't know how to get around this error. Cheers

Comment: Try to use callback functions. They are quite easy to search for. If you still have no clue after reading, come back here. If you can create something, then add this code to the problem so we know how far you are

Comment: HI I tried something new but the problem is that SpalshScreen is not recognizing the command "buttondownfcn". cheers

Answer (score 0):

Ok I see. Since it appears you have at least some programming experience I will not go too deep in on details.

In this [link](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/creating_guis/write-callbacks-using-the-programmatic-workflow.html?refresh=true) you see the the classes using callback functions. What you need to do is to access the handle to the matlab "plot object" (I mean the object that matlab recognices as a `child` in your `figure`) for your SplashScreen object. That object is the one that must be deleted.

More practical, the `buttondownfunction` needs to be applied on the figure `f` and inside `clicky`, you need to delete the object holding the image (which is a matlab object). This would refer to the plottable object which most likely is a member variable to SplashScreen. The easiest way to go should likely be to declare your SplashScreen array (or struct?) global which means that you can easily access it from inside `clicky`. Otherwise you need to do some work to setup a proper gui and use the `handles` input (third input in the callback function) to access your SplashScreen array/struct. Then, let the SplashScreen objects have a **`handle`** member (handle in figure) and also a **`position`** (polygon?). You can have more members of course, but these are neccessary.

If the mouse is inside the polygon when clicky is triggered then delete the handle in the figure and set the member variable to, for example NaN (Since null does not exist in matlab. THis is not really neccessary in matlab, but good practice is to never have references that does not refer to something). Then delete the SplashObject (because it is not used any more).

Remember to delete the globals with `clear global` when you are done, since a normal `clear` or `clear all` does not completely clear globals.

Hope this works. Otherwise please comment.